# Hartree Fock calculations on F2 don't match the traditionally taught MO diagram

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, electronic-configuration

I ran some Hartree-Fock calculations on F2 to visualize the MOs, and the energy levels don't match the trend commonly taught (shown here: https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Heartland_Community_College/HCC%3A_Chem_161/9%3A_Molecular_Geometry_and_Bond_Theory/9.8%3A_M.O._Theory_and_the_Period_2_Diatomic_Molecules).

Instead, I am seeing the pi_2p lower in energy than the sigma_2p. Not sure why they would disagree?

This trend persists with any basis set.

Comment: This is probably due to the lack of correlation effects in HF theory; e.g. the σs and σp orbitals are also switched for N2 as well, in that theory.

Comment: Does using something like b3lyp change the ordering?

Comment: B3LYP does match the MO theory ordering. Either way, it seems silly to assert something in MO theory that HF doesn't capture. Any argument about s-p mixing that people make in drawing molecular orbitals would be included in HF, and MO theory of course doesn't account for things like correlation.